# Store the output from Subquery Factoring in Bulk Collect

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, toad

I want to store the output of query in

```
WITH 
  with_b AS
  (
   Select A, B from Table1
  )
SELECT * 
  FROM 

   (Select A, B from Table2) a, with_b b
WHERE a.A = b.A(+)
order by a.A;
```

into bulk collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define a collection type which matches the projection of the final query. In the code given that would be two columns from `table2` followed by two columns from `table1`.

Something like this:

```
declare
    type ab_rec is record (
       a2 table2.a%type
       , b2 table2.b%type
       , a1 table1.a%type
       , b1 table1.b%type
    );
   type ab_nt is table of ab_rec;
   l_recs ab_nt;
begin
   WITH
    with_b AS
      (
        Select A, B from Table1
      )
    SELECT *
      bulk collect into  l_recs 
    FROM 
          (Select A, B from Table2) a, with_b b
          WHERE a.A = b.A(+)
          order by a.A;
 .....
end;
```